# Prefect : ImportError: cannot import name 'SecretField' from 'pydantic'

Tags: python, pydantic, prefect

I'm currently using prefect to orchestrate some simple task in python. It's working fine until I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from prefect import flow
  File "/Users/.../.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prefect/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from prefect.states import State
...

ImportError: cannot import name 'SecretField' from 'pydantic' (/Users/.../.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.py)
```

It's seems I have the module install in my venv :

```
(.venv) User@user % pip show pydantic
Name: pydantic
Version: 2.3.0
Summary: Data validation using Python type hints
Home-page: None
Author: None
Author-email: Samuel Colvin <s@muelcolvin.com>, Eric Jolibois <em.jolibois@gmail.com>, Hasan Ramezani <hasan.r67@gmail.com>, Adrian Garcia Badaracco <1755071+adriangb@users.noreply.github.com>, Terrence Dorsey <terry@pydantic.dev>, David Montague <david@pydantic.dev>
License: None
Location: /Users.../.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: annotated-types, pydantic-core, typing-extensions
Required-by: prefect, fastapi
```

Where this could come from ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because Perfect isn't compatible with `pydantic>2` yet.
So, they've pinned the reqs to the versions less than 2 (*check [PR10144](https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/pull/10144) for more details*).

Try to install the [`latest`](https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/releases/tag/2.13.1) version of Perfect or downgrade your pydantic's to [`1.10.11`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/releases/tag/v1.10.11) :

```
pip install -U perfect 
# or pip install pydantic==1.10.11
```

Comment: using this command have also work `pip install --upgrade pydantic prefect`